# Visual Studio ( C# ) connection to access database;Not a valid file name”

Tags: c#, database, connection

I was trying to create a new connection to an access data base through Visual studio 2015.

I'm getting this error : Not a valid file name.

Database has .accdb extension.

Name is correct and file exists.
Can someone help me?

thanks.

http://prntscr.com/al2otf

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try and move it to a different directory without a # in the path?

Comment: Yes, the same error is occuring.